# Show that the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} {\log \sin x} \,dx$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Show that this is a convergent integral: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} {\log \sin x} \,dx$$

My approach: I was applying the limit test (refer below), but I am getting the value of $k$ as $0$.

> Limit Comparison Theorem (Type II): If $f$ and $g$ are continuous, positive functions for all values of $x$, and
>   $$\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=k$$
>   if $k$ is nonzero finite, then both integrals 
>   $$\int_{a}^{b} {f(x)}\,dx$$ and $$\int_{a}^{b} {g(x)}\,dx$$ either converge or do not converge.

Comment: good approach,,,,,,

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

Near $0^+$, the integrand has a constant sign.

$$\ln (\sin (x))\approx \ln (x) $$

$$\int_X^1\ln (t)\,dt=-1-X\ln (X)+X $$

and
$$\lim_{X\to 0^+}X\ln (X )=0$$

Answer (score 1):

(1) Show
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log x\,dx$$
converges.

(2) Show
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)\,dx$$
converges.

Comment: that also i tried but how to prove (1). Can you tell me some method or approach to follow for these type of integrals ?.

Comment: You can just **do** the integral in (1).

Comment: @lordsharkoftheunknown Of course, one could evaluate the integral of interest and bypass $(1)$.